# Javascript - Having trouble inserting function

Tags: javascript

I want to add a function that sets vticketqty to 0 if the user enters a non numeric value. I've tried a few things but my code never works properly if i add the function so I'm clearly doing something wrong.

This is the function i was using:

```
function NaN(){
    if (isNaN(TicketQty)) TicketQty = 0;
    } else {
    return TicketQty
}
```

I'm not sure if its correct however, and I'm not entirely sure where the function should be placed within the code. This is my javascript code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var vTicketType;
var vTicketQty;
var vTicketPrice;
function calcTotal() {
    vTicketType = prompt("Enter Ticket Type").toUpperCase();
    document.write("<br>");
    vTicketQty = prompt("Enter No. of Tickets");
    calcPrice();
    vTicketQty = parseInt(vTicketQty);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("Type of Ticket:" + vTicketType);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("Number of Tickets:" + vTicketQty);
    document.write("<br>");
    var vTotalPayment =(vTicketPrice) * (vTicketQty);
    if (vTotalPayment >0) {
        document.write("Total Payment is: $" + vTotalPayment);
        vTicketPrice = parseInt(vTicketPrice);
    } else {
        document.write("INVALID")
    }
}



function calcPrice(){
    if (vTicketType == 'A') {
        vTicketPrice = 50;
    } else if (vTicketType == 'B') {
        vTicketPrice = 30;
    }  else if (vTicketType == 'C'){
      vTicketPrice = 10;
    }
    else {
        vTicketPrice = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` in code that runs after the page is loaded. It will wipe out your page.

Comment: Don't use global variables, use function arguments and return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
> document.write("<br>");
> vTicketQty = prompt("Enter No. of Tickets");
> calcPrice();
> vTicketQty = parseInt(vTicketQty);
> document.write("<br>");
> ```

Try this.

```
document.write("<br>");
while (isNaN(vTicketQty)) {
    vTicketQty = prompt("Enter No. of Tickets");
    calcPrice();
    vTicketQty = parseInt(vTicketQty);
    if (isNaN(vTicketQty)) {
        alert("Quantity must be a number");
    }
}
document.write("<br>");
```

**EDIT** - As requested.

```
document.write("<br>");
vTicketQty = prompt("Enter No. of Tickets");
calcPrice();
vTicketQty = parseInt(vTicketQty);
if (isNaN(vTicketQty)) {
    vTicketQty = 0;
}
document.write("<br>");
```

**EDITED** - more function like

**1)**

```
document.write("<br>");
calcPrice();
vTicketQty = getQty();
document.write("<br>");

function getQty() {
    qty = parseInt(prompt("Enter No. of Tickets"));
    if (isNaN(qty)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return qty;
}
```

**2)**

```
document.write("<br>");
vTicketQty = prompt("Enter No. of Tickets");
calcPrice();
vTicketQty = checkNaN(parseInt(vTicketQty));
document.write("<br>");


function checkNaN(qty) {
    if (isNaN(qty)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return qty;
}
```

Comment: thanks this works, but i'd like ticketqty to be set to 0 rather than the prompt set to a loop. is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I have edited my posted. so that it has both solutions. the solution you require and the original one that someone else may prefer if they are to have a similar problem.

Comment: I've tried both, however my document writes are no longer appearing

Comment: yeah sorry i had a few typos. That caused it to crash and therefore did not work. Should work now. **I have tested both.**